# Azure web job stops running

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a PowerShell script that runs every 5 minutes via the Web Job functionality of a Web App.
Along with the Powershell script I have a settings.job with the following config, which is what makes it tick rather than configuring it as part of the Web job setup:

```
{
    "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
}
```

The job runs successfully each 5 mins for a few hours, but i notice each morning that is has stopped. I'm thinking maybe as a result of an IIS Recycle (?) the job is stopping and then I have to manually kick it off again.

How do I keep it always running?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON) under "Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression":

> This technique is available to Web Apps running in Basic, Standard or Premium mode, and requires the Always On setting to be enabled on the app.

Can you check whether your Web App is using Always On?

Comment: Hmm, I'm on a Shared plan. So it looks like this might not be possible?

Comment: Indeed, it is not. Your options are to upgrade to the Basic plan, or potentially use the Azure Scheduler instead of the CRON approach.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm not able to run a Scheduler instead as it no longer supports powershell which is why I was doing it with the config file. The alternative is to write a web job using the SDK which for me is a bit more than I need at this time.
The job simply connects to an Azure DB and does some work (by means of calling a Stored Procedure) and then closes out - every 5 mins.

Comment: SDK won't help you. If you use a timer trigger, it also requires Always On. It's probably still possible to set up scheduler from PS, but it's harder to configure than CRON.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/) it can run PowerShell scripts and can be kicked off via a Schedule